# Why the addClass is not working in this code

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the below Code of my function when i use CSS it works fine. when I add this CSS to a class it is not working

```
function setTab(selection) {
        $("#"+selection).css('background', '#CC0000');
        $("#"+selection).css('color', '#ffffff');   
        // Both the Above statements works fine     
        $("#"+selection).addClass("selectedclass");//doesnot work 
    }   

    .selectedclass li{
        background: #CC0000;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give further detail as to the markup and how this function is being called? This looks fine from what you're showing. (Also, just as an optimization note, you should be caching the `$("#"+selection)` jQuery object, as creating new jQuery objects is expensive.)

Comment: Verify if the class is actually added or not (firebug is your friend). Maybe you just have some error in your CSS...

Comment: post more code or a live example; the above code is correct (as well as yahelc; +1)

Comment: I suspect you're adding the class to the `li` element directly. That CSS rule works only if it's applied to the *parent* of a `li` element.

Comment: The only thing I could imagine is a problem with selector precedence. E.g. if you have already a css selector on the ul/ol or any parent, that has more weight than this selector e.g. `#list li { ... }'

Comment: @all: when i look in F12 in IE there is no class Applied what might be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I bet is happening is that the class is being overruled by another style. Which is the the most obvious in this case. The reason the first two lines of code work is becaue they edit the style directly, where adding a class, the cascading rules still would apply

Try these:

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* I'm guess at what I think you need, since I don't know your HTML structure. */
    body .selectedclass li,
    body ul .selectedclass li ,
    body ol .selectedclass li {
        background: #CC0000;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
```

Your code is simple, so it's probably correct. But you could clean it up a bit like so:

```
function setTab(selection)
{
    if ( typeof(selection) == "string" )
    {
        $( '#' + selection ).addClass( "selectedclass" );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is a more specific selector than the class selector being applied? Have you looked at the element in Firebug to see where the element is getting its properties?   Using the first two statements, you're setting the style directly on the element, which will take precedence.  Using the second, it will depend on the various styles that you have defined, their order and specificity.  Could also be that your class is applied to the wrong element, i.e., directly to the `li` instead of the parent `ul` (`ol`).  In that case you need to change your rule to `li.selectedClass`.

Also, did you know that you can chain the jQuery functions together? And `css` has an overload that takes a map of key/value pairs.

```
function setTab(selection) {
    $("#"+selection).css({'background-color': '#CC0000', 'color' : '#ffffff'});
}
```